# How to store get response data in angular 5 with JWT Token

Tags: angular, angular5, typescript2.0, angular4-httpclient

```
getEmployeeList():Observable<Employee[]>{
  return this.http.get<Employee[]>('moi/employee/getEmp', AuthService.getHttpOptions());
}
```

and my `AuthService.getHttpOptions()` method is:

```
 public static getHttpOptions(): any {''
    var httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'observe': "body",
            'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("authtoken")
          })
    };
    return httpOptions;
}
```

Got the error:

> Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<Employee[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Employee[]>'.
>
> Type 'HttpEvent<Employee[]>' is not assignable to type 'Employee[]'.
>
> Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type 'Employee[]'.
>
> Property 'includes' is missing in type 'HttpSentEvent'.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: When I add the Observable<HttpEvent<Employee[]>> instead of Observable<Employee[]> then its work fine but I got the same error in employee.component.ts

Comment: Sorry guys I did the small mistake. I got the answer now thank

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http,Headers,RequestOptions }  from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';
export Class serviceName{
  authToken;
  headers;
  // After login we have already store jwt token on the localstorage
  constructor(private _http:Http,private _router:Router) { 
    this.loadToken();
    this.headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 
     'Bareer '+this.authToken});
   }
   loadToken(){
     this.authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
   }
  createAuthenticateHeaders(){
    this.loadToken();
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      'headers':new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization':this.authToken
      })
    });
  }
   getEmployeeList(userInfo){
    this.createAuthenticateHeaders();
    return this._http.get(this.domain+'/products', {headers:this.headers})
     .map(response => response.json());
   }
 }
```

You can bind token like this way.
Steps

- Do login and generate authtoken
- Store token in sessionstorage.`enter code here`
- Then in constructor of a service load that token.
- Then Create headers
- Call any service method with passing token in the header.